# App Store ID & a different iCloud ID?

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore, apple-id

I have two sperate Apple ID accounts as I had to factory reset my phone, I created a new one a few months ago. My first Apple ID (before the factory reset) can connect with iCloud, but not the App Store - there is a problem with this one about billing on it but I've never purchased anything only free apps, so it doesn't let me update any apps or my phone software. After the factory reset my second Apple ID works with the App Store, but I'm not able to access iCloud because of my security questions (can't reset them either :(). & I would like to have all my music & pictures on there. So I was wondering if there was a way to keep the first Apple ID logged into my iCloud & the second Apple ID logged into my iTunes & App Store?

Anything would be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on how to set this up on Apple's support site, see towards the end of https://support.apple.com/HT204053.

Basically you open Settings on your iOS device and

- configure/use one AppleID to log into iCloud
- configure/use the other ID to log into iTunes & App Store

Having said that, I would still recommend to address the issues you have with your current account. To verify your billing details, log into the Store and update your information (if it doesn't work in the iOS device, you can use any computer running iTunes for this, just don't forget to log out within iTunes afterwards); to recover your second account, start with https://iforgot.apple.com/.

Comment: Okay, thank you! & sadly, I've tried many times to edit all my information - just did again a few minuets ago, but it's saying my card number is wrong, witch isn't true because I do my banking with it. & there's also no purchases to pay for. As for recovering my second account, I spoke with Apple on the phone yesterday (before I thought of two Apple IDs) & there's no way to reset my questions :/